# Working with Many to Many and GreenDao 3.1.0 - Android

Tags: android, greendao, greendao3

I have 2 Entities Mood, MoodNote, both of them I get them from webservice as 1 json list.

Json sample:

```
{  
  "id":1,
  "name":"Sad",
  "created_at":"2016-08-11 19:59:43",
  "updated_at":"2016-08-16 20:15:17",
  "deleted_at":null,
  "symbol":"\\uD83D\\uDE22",
  "notes":[
    {  
      "id":409,
      "content":"Recusandae necessitatibus numquam consectetur ut.",
      "created_at":"2016-08-11 20:01:18",
      "updated_at":"2016-08-11 20:01:18",
      "deleted_at":null,
      "count":0,
      "pivot":{  
        "id_mood":1,
        "id_modenote":409,
        "created_at":"2016-08-11 20:01:19",
        "updated_at":"2016-08-11 20:01:19"
      }
    },
    {  
      "id":269,
      "content":"Nulla laudantiums quia impedit.",
      "created_at":"2016-08-11 20:01:18",
      "updated_at":"2016-08-11 20:01:18",
      "deleted_at":null,
      "count":0,
      "pivot":{  
        "id_mood":1,
        "id_modenote":269,
        "created_at":"2016-08-11 20:01:19",
        "updated_at":"2016-08-11 20:01:19"
      }
    },
    {  
      "id":204,
      "content":"Incidunt doloremque",
      "created_at":"2016-08-11 20:01:18",
      "updated_at":"2016-08-11 20:01:18",
      "deleted_at":null,
      "count":0,
      "pivot":{  
        "id_mood":1,
        "id_modenote":204,
        "created_at":"2016-08-11 20:01:19",
        "updated_at":"2016-08-11 20:01:19"
      }
    },
  ]
}
```

The relation between them is many to many.

now this is the entities classes:

```
@Entity
public class Mood {
    @Id
    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private Long id;
    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    private String name;
    @SerializedName("created_at")
    @Expose
    private String createdAt;
    @SerializedName("updated_at")
    @Expose
    private String updatedAt;
    @SerializedName("deleted_at")
    @Expose
    private String deletedAt;
    @SerializedName("symbol")
    @Expose
    private String symbol;

    @ToMany
    @JoinEntity(
            entity = JoinMoodNote.class,
            sourceProperty = "moodId",
            targetProperty = "moodNoteId"
    )
    @SerializedName("notes")
    @Expose
    private List<MoodNote> notes = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

The mood note:

```
@Entity
public class MoodNote {
    @Id
    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private Long id;
    @SerializedName("content")
    @Expose
    private String content;
    @SerializedName("created_at")
    @Expose
    private String createdAt;
    @SerializedName("updated_at")
    @Expose
    private String updatedAt;
    @SerializedName("deleted_at")
    @Expose
    private String deletedAt;
    @SerializedName("count")
    @Expose
    private int count;
}
```

And in [this tutorial : LINK](http://greenrobot.org/greendao/documentation/updating-to-greendao-3-and-annotations/#Relation_annotations_ToOne_ToMany_etc) , they mentioned to do like this

```
@Entity
public class JoinMoodNote {
    @Id private Long id;
    private Long moodId;
    private Long moodNoteId;
}
```

they did not mention after that how to set or get data

I need any example of ManyToMany or a hint of its usage.

I tried to get the Mood using retrofit and I got list of moods

```
// This only insert the moods, it doesnt insert the MoodNote list
moodDao.insertTx(moods);
```

Comment: Hi, Did you finally solve this problem? I am facing the same problem.

Comment: @AsmeJust please check the answer, i have posted it down below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem by adding the records to the database manually:

```
moodDao.insertInTx(moodsList); // inserting all moods 
daoSession.runInTx(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Foreach mood get the moodNotesList and add it to database
        for (Mood mood : moodsList) {
            long moodId = mood.getId();
            for (MoodNote note : mood.getMoodNotes()) {
                note.setMoodId(moodId); // nothing but set the moodId of the MoodNote to keep the relation
                moodNoteDao.insert(note); // insert the moodNote to database one by one
            }
        }
    }
});
```

This is not the perfect solution, but it solved my problem.

If i find a better solution i will post it back here, if you have a better solution please post is as answer so we learn it.

Thank you.

Comment: I see what you're trying to do here. And it's kinda complicated for me. I just don't understand why they didn't made a more detailed doc for many-to-many case. Or a working example at least.

Comment: @AsmeJust what i am trying to do here is getting the list of MoodNotes, and add them one by one to the database, because i think the library doesnt support adding them at once.

Comment: Ohh, OK, I got it now. I take a second look at the code and found out that it's not that complicated lol. But why did you put it in a Runnable?

Comment: @AsmeJust daoSession.runInTx means run the code in transaction which make it faster to add alot of records to database. you can use insertInTx(moodNotesList)   .. it works the same

Comment: Join me here whenever you're free http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126661/onetomany-using-greendao

Comment: How we can set the property like MoodId by MoodNote entity as that property is not a part of it. it is part of JoinMoodNote. I very new to greendao. Can you please explain how we can set these foreign key in JoinMoodNote.

Comment: @Hemant Actually JoinMoodNote works only when I try to get from database, I set moodId when i insert to database because JoinMoodNote is not working when I try to insert to database.